# Posting front-end form to plugin controller route results in 404

Tags: plugin-development, form

I'm working on a plugin and need a front-end (non CP) form that submits to one of the plugin controllers. Here's my setup:

```
- plugins
  - portal
    -- PortalPlugin.php
    - controller
      -- Portal_AccessController.php
```

**Portal_AccessController.php**

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

class Portal_AccessController extends BaseController {

    protected $allowAnonymous = true;

    public function actionLogin() {

        echo 'Here';

    }

}
```

I then created a front-end form by adding a new template directory in `/craft/templates`:

```
- pro-portal
  -- index.html
```

With `index.html` containing:

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="portal/access/login">

    <div>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4">
        <input type="text" maxlength="4">
        <input type="text" maxlength="4">
        <input type="text" maxlength="4">
    </div>
    <a href="{{ actionUrl('portal/access/login') }}">Test me</a>
    <input class="btn submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Hitting `mydomain.com/pro-portal` displays the form. On submit it returns to `/pro-portal` but with a 404 error.

I also tried creating an action link but that also results in a 404 at `/index.php/actions/portal/access/login`.

I've looked through answers on similar questions and tried all the solutions but no luck. Am I overlooking something? Missing something?

Comment: What's `$response['redirect']` and where is it coming from?

Comment: I tried passing in a redirect parameter to redirect to a new URL. That's not in my code at the moment. I've update the question to show that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a 404 because your action method isn't telling Craft what do to after it has echo'd 'Here', so [routing](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing) continues.

See #3 is that link:

```
The request doesn’t necessarily end after a controller has been called. The controller may allow it to keep going.
```

You can redirect, end the request, load up a template to display, etc.

**Update:**

The `controller` folder needs to be renamed to `controllers`.

Comment: So if I put something like `$this->redirect('http://google.com');` in my controller method it should redirect, but I'm still being returned to `/pro-portal` and getting the 404 page.

Comment: If you put a `die();` after the echo, do you see the text?

Comment: No. I get the 404 page.

Comment: Oh, it's not even making it to the action then. Rename your `controller` folder to `controllers`.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like that. Thank you!